# Find and replace in matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want do find and replace all in matlab (As we do in MS office).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxfqunjwhnvkl1f/matlab.mat?dl=0

I have a cell array `LUT_HS_complete` (contains identifier in column 1 and protein name in column 2 and summary in column 3) this is my look up table. on the other hand, I have my protein-protein interaction data (named `Second_layer` with identifiers in first two columns and the score in column 3).

I want to replace the first two columns in my `Second_layer` with the corresponding protein name from my look up table.

I tried `strmatch`, but that didn't help me.

```
Source_gene = Second_layer(:,1); Source_gene = regexprep(Source_gene,'[-/\s]','');
Target_gene = Second_layer(:,2); Target_gene = regexprep(Target_gene,'[-/\s]','');
Inter_score = Second_layer(:,3);

%%
for i=1:length(Source_gene(1:end,1));
    SG = strmatch(Source_gene(i),LUT_HS_complete(1:end,1),'exact');
    renamed_Source_gene(SG,1) = LUT_HS_complete(SG,2);
end

for j=1:length(Target_gene(1:end,1));
    TG = strmatch(Target_gene(j),LUT_HS_complete(1:end,1),'exact');
    renamed_Target_gene(TG,1) = LUT_HS_complete(TG,2);
end
```

If you could find a solution. It would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Might this work for you?

```
renamed_Second_layer(:,1)=LUT_HS_complete(cellfun(@(x) find(strcmp(x,LUT_HS_complete(:,1))),Second_layer(:,1)),2);
renamed_Second_layer(:,2)=LUT_HS_complete(cellfun(@(x) find(strcmp(x,LUT_HS_complete(:,1))),Second_layer(:,2)),2);
renamed_Second_layer(:,3)=Second_layer(:,3);
```